# RegEx pattern to search for numbers in Google Apps Script (Javascript 1.6)

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I have an array of numbers from 0 to 10 ["0", "1", ..., "10"] and i'm using `text.search(array[i])` where the text contains "10" (This is 10). The code always find "1" but not "10". Can i create a `RegExp` to find `10`?

Thanks a lot.

```
function analizar(text) {
  var querer =  ["baja", "muestra", "ver", "imprim"];
  var tema = ["contenido", "asunto", "materia", "texto", "leccion"];
  var temas =[" 0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];

  var keys = [querer, tema, temas];
  var resultado = 0;

  var str = []
  for (var a = 0; a < keys.length; a++){
    for (var b = 0; b < keys[a].length; b++){

      var actual = keys[a];
      var buscar = actual[b];
```

here is the issue. I don't know how search exact for number 10

```
      if (a == "2") {var buscar = new RegExp(actual[b]);}
      var val = text.search (buscar)
      if (val > -1) {
        resultado++;
        if(a == "2") {str.push(keys[a][b])}
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  Logger.log(str[0]);

  if (resultado == 3) {return str[0]}
  if (resultado != 3) {return "";}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is you search low to high through the numbers. This will mean we find `1` and return whereas we should have been greedy and matched the `0` after the `1` to match the full `10`.

So just rearranging your array:

`var temas =[ "10", " 0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];`

should give correct output.

However you are not at all using regexes for their true power. A single regular expression could describe that whole array:

`/10?|[2-9]| 0/`

Regex breakdown:

`10?` : match a character `1` that occurs exactly once followed by `0` either 1 or 0 times. (*this captures the `1` case and the `10` case*)
`|` : This is an `OR` operation. Match either the expression to the left or to the right.
`[2-9]` : match a single character in the range `2` to `9`
`|` : another `OR`
`0` : match the character  exactly once followed by exactly one `0` character.

Answer (score 1):

The problem ist the order of your regexp strings in the `temas` array. Since you are checking the string for `1` and after that for `10`, any string containing `10` will always match `1`. Since you are breaking after you have a match, you will never get to `10`.

You need to move `10` in front of `1` then it will work as expected.

```
var temas =[" 0", "10", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's perfect solution